# Google Chrome Extension to access database of Google Calendar

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I am developing an extension for google chrome. I want it to connect to google calendar database.

I am trying to extend functionality of Google Calendar Tasks using my extension. So when user want to add those specific tasks to the calendar, how to access database at that time.

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to understand the following APIs for you to be able to develop your indented extension

1. [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview)
2. [Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)